# What does the 'mouse cursor in a box' button do?

Tags: steam, steam-link

When configuring touch controls on the Steam Link iOS app, there's a button in the bottom right of a white mouse cursor inside a box. Clicking it toggles whether the white mouse cursor is inside or outside the box.

What does this button of a mouse cursor inside a box do?

[image: arrow pointing to mouse icon]

Comment: Don't you just love how we're going back to pictograms with a perfectly good alphabet just sitting there...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Steam Link Touch Controller Guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1888830141):

> **Hide Cursor at game launch**
> Pressing this will hide the cursor at the bottom-right corner of the screen. This is useful for when you are using gamepad controls to play a game but the game does not automatically hide the cursor.